# Calculate number of defects(PMF of sum of multinomial distributions)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose you have two factories, A and B which produce two items at the same time with a probability of defect from A, $p_A$ and probability of defect from B, $p_B$

Suppose a total of $N_T$ items are made so $\frac{N_T}{2}$ from each. How would you compute the probability that $N_d$ items are defective?

It looks like you can consider this to be a sum of multinomial distributions as supposing $X_A$ represents the number of defects out of $\frac{N_T}{2}$ from factory A and $X_B$ represents the number of defects out of $\frac{N_T}{2}$ from factory B both are distributed according to multinomial distribution and we are interested in $P(X_A + X_B = N_d)$

I don't see any closed form solution to computing this probability without summing the probability of every combination which sums to $N_d$

Comment: Given $N_T$ is large you can use normal approximation for binomial

Comment: If $p_A=p_B, X_A+X_B$ is also a binomial distribution with parameters $N_T, p_A$.

Comment: [The result of the summation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+binom+%28n%2Ck%29+*+binom%28n%2Cm-k%29+*+q%5Ek+for+k%3D0..m&dataset=) can be expressed using the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function); I doubt that you'll find a more closed form for it than that.